# Our back-end call result isn't reaching the front-end, the network call has extremely long waiting times it seems, what could be the issue?

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, http, https

We have a ReactJS front-end working with a C# .NET back-end. Last week everything seemed fine, I didn't change anything related to the call in question now and now we try it this morning and it just ... Stalls?

We debug our back-end and everything seems fine, a result is produced by our services and seemingly returned by our controller. But then in the front-end it just seems to stall & never receive anything? Nothing was changed to the DTOs or models or anything, and even if it would fail, it should show something has failed like "bad request" or "internal server error" or something right?

I tried running it on my machine and the Google Chrome network stats said it was TTFB (time to first byte) took over 3 minutes, then it was "downloading" the content and it took over 10 minutes, then I quit my browser.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and what we should look into? It seems so weird to us just happening now, with the same service code, controller return, DTO & models, etc...

Also we use the same "way" of getting & producing the result to the front-end for other screens, and there are NO issues on the other screens, just on this one... ?

Disclaimer, we're also using "axios" in the front-end to handle some interceptors and do other stuff, but it's been in there since day 1 and doesn't seem to produce issues for all our other screens & components...

Does anyone have even the slightest idea of where to look? I'm baffled and never had this before!

Comment: did you try to perform your requests from another client (not your frontend application) but something like ARC?

Comment: I'll try, but something weird is that Google Chrome, for that one call, seems to be suddenly downloading 6GB of data? Crazy!

Comment: With swagger it returns in a few seconds...

Comment: 6 GB of data sounds strange, but not impossible (Value Filter inside your controller could be off), if you handle such amounts with your controller. If you stream this amount of data from your service you should also be able to see where it comes from. if you return objects which reference there parent they could be caught inside a serialization loop and generate a huge response.

Comment: After a grueling day of staring at the problem we've found the issue, it was due to some automatic merge I believe that added some DOMAIN entities (virtual List etc...) to a DTO, so whenever that was called, I believe all the domain entities & relationships etc... were pulled and caused maybe some circular dependencies as well... 

But eventually we found it! :)